# Badly generates a cell view. The first element is displayed correctly and the rest is wrong

Tags: ios, swift

Badly generates a cell view. The first element is displayed correctly and the rest is wrong.

```
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        return layer
    }()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,0.6,1]
    gradientLayer.frame = blur.bounds
    blur.layer.mask = gradientLayer
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    gradientLayer.frame = blur.bounds
}
```

Example Image:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4kxR.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the frame isn't correct in that method.

You should be updating the frame in this method inside your `UITableViewController`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = //YOUR CELL
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.gradientLayer.frame = blur.bounds
}
```

Comment: can you show the entire code then? Would need to see the rest of the code